# View commit's code lines counter in WebStorm

Tags: git, github, webstorm

When you create a pull request in GitHub, you can see the lines of code removed and added counter 
[image]

I'm wondering if you can see similar statistic before you commit a change in WebStorm. Is there a plugin of some sort for it because I had a look around WebStorm and couldn't see such feature.

Comment: You can use any `git GUI`, like gitk, gitkraken, etc. I'm not sure if WebStorm has any plugins for this feature.

Comment: [This](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox) seems to be a popular plugin

Comment: Played around GitToolBox and it seems that it only offers this once you actually commit your change. I was looking for something to show the counter without the need to commit.

Comment: Using a git GUI will solve this